# Java Could not load or find main class

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to code a java program.  I want this program to basically open an application, but have it all in one area.. (Windows already has it done.. but w/e).
When I open this program, as it says in the title, I get the error "Could not load or find main class"  I have no idea why I'm getting this, as most of the other programs I have made don't have this issue.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.javaapplication10;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Ethan
 */
public class javaapplication10 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form javaapplication10
     */
    public javaapplication10() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Minecraft");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("FTB");

        jButton3.setText("Tekkit");

        jButton4.setText("Chrome");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 try {
      String line;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd C:\\Users\\Ethan\\Desktop\\minecraft.bat");
      BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
      while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      bri.close();
      while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      bre.close();
      p.waitFor();
      System.out.println("Done.");
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }                                        
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaapplication10.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaapplication10.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaapplication10.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaapplication10.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new javaapplication10().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

In netbeans, I have something that looks like this:
"JavaApplication10"
"source packages"
    "javaapplication10"
          "javaapplication10.java"

Comment: Run it how?  Is it Jar'ed or are you running from within Netbeans?  If it's Jar'ed, have you set the `Main-Class` entry in the MANIFEST.mf file?

Comment: Thanks madprogrammer, again, but how do I set the main class?  What do I add?

Comment: From Netbeans, right click the project node in the `Projects` tab, select `Properties`.  Browse to the `Run` node.  Where it says `Main Class`, select `Browse` and select the class you want to executed.  Presumably that would be `javaapplication10`

Comment: Aside from what MadProgrammer said, to run your code from NetBeans you can also click on your `.java` file (in your case `javaapplication10.java`) and use "Run File" or press Ctrl+F6

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Make sure your **Main Class** field is having correct value. In your case, it should be `org.javaapplication10.javaapplication10`